# Move cells with pattern search and copy

Tags: excel, search, move

I would like to achieve following in VBA

```
Input Workbook1 
Index   Value 
 1       a
 2       a
 3       b
 4       c
 5       a
 6       b
 7       a
 8       c
```

Output Workbook2

I would like to have output in following format so that I can generate graph with same X axis

```
Index   Value 1 Value 2     Value 3
1        a      
2        a      
3                b  
4                             c 
5        a      
6                b  
7        a      
8                             c
```

I am using two functions, the first one to move two columns from workbook 1 to workbook2

```
Sub MOVE() 
    Sheets("Workbook1").Columns("A").Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    Sheets("Workbook1").Columns("B").Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")`
end sub
```

2nd function is:

```
Sub move_a() 
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate 
    Dim myR As Range 
    Set myR = Range("B:B").Find("PATTERN_A") 
    Do While Not myR Is Nothing
         myR.Insert xlToRight 
        Set myR = Range("B:B").FindNext 
    Loop
end sub
```

but 2nd one is not working

Comment: I am first timer in Excel. any feedback highly appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to SO - could you please post any code that you have tried so far, and the output it produced so that we can narrow down your problem. Thank you.

Comment: Sub MOVE()
Sheets("Workbook1").Columns("A").Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
Sheets("Workbook1").Columns("B").Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
End Sub

Sub move_a()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Dim myR As Range
Set myR = Range("B:B").Find("PATTERN_A")
Do While Not myR Is Nothing
   myR.Insert xlToRight
   Set myR = Range("B:B").FindNext
Loop

Comment: I am using two functions first one to move two column from workbook 1 to workbook2   Sub MOVE()
Sheets("Workbook1").Columns("A").Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
Sheets("Workbook1").Columns("B").Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
End Sub

Comment: 2nd function is Sub move_a()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Dim myR As Range
Set myR = Range("B:B").Find("PATTERN_A")
Do While Not myR Is Nothing
   myR.Insert xlToRight
   Set myR = Range("B:B").FindNext
Loop

Comment: but 2nd one is not working

Comment: @PeterBailey - ... and people can retract their Close votes on an edited question.

Comment: @Jeeped ah OK yes, will remove my comments here too that are no longer relevant, to tidy up the comment trail to only what's relevant now.

Comment: Would a pivot table do an acceptable job?  You'd get a, b and c instead of value1, value2 and value3 and a count of what's in each Index - so the same pattern as your example output, but with 1's instead of letters.

Answer (score 0):

I've put your two operations into a single sub procedure. First the copy is performed on the entire block and then cells are inserted according to the value in column B to shift the values to the right.

```
Sub move_it_all()
    Dim rw As Long, a As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Worksheets("Workbook1").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Copy _
            Destination:=.Cells(1, 1)
        For rw = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            a = Asc(UCase(Right(.Cells(rw, 2).Value2, 1)))
            If a > 65 And a <= 90 Then
                .Cells(rw, 2).Resize(1, a - 65).Insert shift:=xlToRight
            End If
            .Cells(1, a - 63) = "Value" & a - 64
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

I will admit to some confusion over the worksheet named *Workbook1*. You might have to adjust the source and target of the Copy & Paste.

[image: Before and After]